# C++ if/else grid system

Tags: c++, function, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create a C++ program that will move an X on a 4x4 grid and display each move.  We are not allowed to use arrays because we haven't learned how yet.  I know that I am supposed to use 16 if/else statements, but I am not sure what to do from there.  I know there is an easier way than mapping out each possible option because that would take forever!!! What do I do???

EDIT: It is only allowed to move up/down/left/right.  And what I mean by display each move it is first supposed to display the user's starting point (which I've already set up) and then it is supposed to print grids with successive moves on them including all of the previous moves until it reaches the end point.

Comment: 4x4 = 16, right? ;) So I think you're supposed to do just that, however dubious this teaching method could be... Arrays are the real solution there.

Comment: In what pattern is the X supposed to move? (Should it move one cell up/down/left/right at a time based on user input?) Is there anything else on the grid that needs to be displayed?

Comment: You do not have to use arrays. Only check if your move could end outside of the area, and deny those moves. `if ((new_x>=0) || (new_x<=3) || (new_y>=0) || (new_y<=3)) { ..do_move..};` Start at definite position. Move will shift coordinate by some fixed value. That's all.

Comment: Interestingly this is a C++ question, then you can make a `class X`, with two members, `int x` and `int y`, and a move method `move(int dx, int dy)`, and a `whereAmI()` method to print out the location. Rasterizing the grid into a 2D array doesn't sound right.

Comment: @user3528438 If they haven't learned arrays yet, it is very likely they have not learned classes ;)

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "move an X on a 4x4 grid and display each move"? I need more details from which I can understand what exactly should the program do.

Comment: The question is still not clear whether the history needs to be recorded. If it's a "real-time" design, then it only prints locations right after the move, then a record of current location is sufficient. However if you want the user to make the moves first and print out the movement history at the end (maybe animated), then it's impossible to get away without an array (or a list, a queue, a stack)

Answer (score 2):

Note: I originally wrote this answer based on assumptions about the task that turned out to be wrong. However, I'll leave the answer up as I believe it might still contain useful information for the OP.

When you have *x* different possible situations, you don't always need an `if`/`else` with *x* branches. The trick is to find a way to use the *same* computation (typically one or more mathematical expressions, and possibly loops) to handle all or most of the situations.

In this case, there are indeed 16 different positions on a 4x4 grid, and one way to represent a position is to store its row and column number (each a value between 0 and 3). By using two loops, one inside the other (*nested* loops), you can generate all 16 combinations of row and column position. I'll assume now that you're supposed to print e.g. `.` on the empty cells of the grid. Inside the inner loop, you need to figure out whether you should print a `.` or an `X`. What question should you ask in order to figure that out? Simply "is the row and column number that the nested loops are currently at the same row and column number as the location of the X?"

Edit after seeing your update: Even when working with a grid, arrays are only needed when you have to store information about every cell, so one can sometimes get away without an array if you can *generate* the grid information from fewer pieces of information (such as the position of the X). However, if you need to keep track of the previous positions, you need an array (either one- or two-dimensional) in order to do it elegantly. I would say that the "no arrays" restriction of this task is not educational, as it forces an unnatural and very cumbersome way to solve this task. :-( (However, if your instructor subsequently gives the same task and allows you to use loops, it will be a good demonstration of why loops are useful.)

What you could do is to use 16 `bool` variables (all set to `false` initially) with names such as `grid00`, `grid01`, `grid02`, `grid03`, `grid10`, ..., `grid33`. Then make two methods, `bool isOccupied(int row, int column)` and `void occupy(int row, int column)` that use 16-way `if`/`else` statements to allow you to easily read and change the variable that corresponds to a given position.

Answer (score 0):

> *I know that I am supposed to use 16 if/else statements, but I am not
>   sure what to do from there.*

If this is a constraint on your solution given to your by your instructor, that means that you will need to handle each of the 16 possible grid locations in a separate {} block. You'll have to have an enum representing each of the pairs. like:

e_1_1, e_1_2, e_1_3, e_1_4,

e_2_1, e_2_2, e_2_3, e_2_4,

e_3_1, e_3_2, e_3_3, e_3_4,

e_4_1, e_4_2, e_4_3, e_4_4,

and you'll have to manually update the current position to a new one in the switch statement. Keep track of your current position in a variable called something like 'position'.

> I know there is an easier way than mapping out each possible option
>   because that would take forever!!!

Welcome to programming. ;-)

Copy and paste is your friend and this problem of having to write a lot of similar but slightly different code is fairly common to many programming tasks. Becoming a good programmer means learning how to avoid largely duplicate code when possible. You are not there yet, or you wouldn't have to ask. So this first step will be an important lesson for you. A bit of pain will help you appreciate how much better the approach you will use the next time will be.

But this isn't that much work. An experienced C++ programmer could knock this out in less than 5 to 10 minutes. Moderately experienced, perhaps 20 to 30. It might take a learning programmer a few hours or more.

There are more concise ways to handle this problem without requiring 16 separate blocks, however, none of them are easier to understand. If this a requirement for a class learning project, then you will find it beneficial to do it first this way, then as a next step, try to do it with more complex logic.

**Suggestions**

An experienced programmer would define the move possibilities as an enum. Then the moves would be handled inside the {} blocks for the if statements using a switch statement that handled each of the four enums corresponding to the four moves. If you don't know the switch statement yet you can use an if ... else if ... else if ... that checks for each of the four moves.

Start with handling just the first upper left corner position moves for a smaller 2 x 2 grid. Then add each of the other three positions for the 2 x 2 grid. Once you have that working you should be able to understand easily how to extend the solution to a 4 x 4 and arbitrarily larger grid.

You'll want to have a function that prints the position array that gets called after every move. For now, you'll have to check the value of the enum and print manually. Something like:

1. Is position == e_1_1? print '* else print '_'
2. Is position == e_1_2? print '* else print '_'
3. Is position == e_1_3? print '* else print '_'
4. Is position == e_1_4? print '* else print '_'
5. print a newline
6. Is position == e_2_1? print '* else print '_'
7. Is position == e_2_2? print '* else print '_'
8. Is position == e_2_3? print '* else print '_'
9. Is position == e_2_4? print '* else print '_'
10. etc.

Some pointers for easy debugging:

Set the values for an enum for up, down, left, and right to something you can print out and follow easily, i.e. e_up = 'u' and e_down = 'd'. That will make it easier to debug if you don't have an IDE that will let you easily see the enum values, and you can print out the moves directly in the beginning.

Make your changes to the code in small increments. Run the code and once you know that the part you added works, move on. If you add too much at once it is much harder to figure out where things are broken, especially when you are new.

**Future Solution with Arrays**

Some hints: You'll want to use a two-dimensional array.

Try this on a 2 x 2 array first to make your life simpler. Then when the logic works, change the array size. To make this process easier use a const integer to define a value that you use to define the arrays and the printing using a for loop so that when you change the constant from:

const int array_size = 2

to

const int array_size = 4

the rest of the code will just work. For extra credit, support arrays of differing height and width by using separate constants for array_height and array_width. Learn to do it well and the way a pro would do it and you'll develop pro habits and earn pro wages much more quickly.

Remember to use a for loop for printing the rows and columns that uses the constants you defined.

You'll want to have the code running a loop looking for input, then processing the move, then printing out the new grid.